# What would be the better way to do a function pointer for GUI input?

Tags: user-interface, input, widget, controls, function-pointers

I Am currently working on an open source Game engine in C for people to learn from etc and i was wondering what would be the best way to do the input for The UI system via mouse clicks, key press's etc.

Currently i have the the ui system's input using function pointers where to set a function the user would just go.

```
button1.mousepress = button1_press;
```

then if the user clicked button1 it would loop through to find button 1 then do button1's click event. however i need it to go to a event inside of the control then to the users control. The way i have the function pointers setup is as follows.

```
struct widget
{
//contains control special data
void *control;

//contains the parent of the widget.
widget *parent;

//contains events for quick calling
void(*draw)(widget *);
void(*mousepress)(widget *,int,int);
void(*mouserelease)(widget *,int,int);
void(*mousewheel)(widget *,int);
void(*keypressed)(widget *,int,int);

//hidden and shown arrays
widget_array shown;
widget_array hidden;

vector2ui pos;
vector2ui actualpos;
vector2ui originalpos;
vector2i imgpos;
image img;
uint16 width;
uint16 height;
uint8 type;
sbool action;
};
```

As you can see the function pointers are not generic at the moment, so if i have to make them generic i will. other than that what would be the best way to set the function pointers up to allow them to go into the gui controls Event then go to the user made 
**button1.mousepress**. Any ideas on what the best method for doing thins would be. A friend of mine suggested Chaining but i could not figure out how chaining works....

Thank you for any of you who read through this, as well as thank you to those whom will help.